# How to intentionally create .dep files?

Tags: c, makefile, embedded, gnu-make, preprocessor

I have 5 source files (main.c, memory.c, etc) I want to generate dependency files for all of them .dep

When I searched online I found that most people only suffer from those files created by compiler, and some are solving this by adding them forcefully to a directory. But, I want to intentionally create them to be (main.dep, memory.dep, etc)

how can I have the make create them automatically for me by my command:

```
$ make build
```

I guess it will be some kind of order I will put in CPPFLAGS, then include CPPFLAGS into my $(TARGET).out recipe, but I don't know what exactly. any ideas?

here's my Makefile right now:

```
include sources.mk

# Platform Overrides

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),MSP432)

# Architectures Specific Flags
LINKER_FILE = msp432p401r.lds
CPU = cortex-m4
ARCH = thumb
SPECS = nosys.specs
COMPILE = -DMSP432
LDFLAGS_ARCH = -T $(LINKER_FILE)
CFLAGS_ARCH = -mcpu=$(CPU) -m$(ARCH) --specs=$(SPECS) -march=armv7e-m 
-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
DUMP = arm-none-eabi-objdump

# Compiler Flags and Defines
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-ld

endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),HOST)
OBJS = $(SOURCES_BOTH:.c=.o)
COMPILE = -DHOST
CC = gcc
DUMP = objdump
endif


TARGET = c1m2
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(TARGET).map $(LDFLAGS_ARCH)
CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS_ARCH) $(INCLUDES)  -Wall -Werror -g -O0  -std=c99 
$(COMPILE)
CPPFLAGS =


.PHONY: build
build: $(TARGET).out

.PHONY: compile-all
compile-all: $(OBJS)

CLEANO = main.o memory.o interrupts_msp432p401r_gcc.o 
startup_msp432p401r_gcc.o system_msp432p401r.o
CLEANI = main.i memory.i interrupts_msp432p401r_gcc.i 
startup_msp432p401r_gcc.i system_msp432p401r.i
CLEANASM = main.asm memory.asm interrupts_msp432p401r_gcc.asm 
startup_msp432p401r_gcc.asm system_msp432p401r.asm

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET).out $(TARGET).map $(CLEANO) $(CLEANI) $(CLEANASM)

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

%.i : %.c
    $(CC) -E $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

%.asm :  %.o
$(DUMP) -S --disassemble $< > $@

$(TARGET).out: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add one line to the compilation step:

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

would become:

```
%.o : %.c
    # dep generation
    $(CC) -MM $< > $<.dep
    # compilation 
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

---

If you want dependency files extension to be `.dep` instead of `.c.dep`, you can adjust this rule:

```
%.o : %.c
    # dep generation
    $(CC) -MM $< > $(patsubst %.c,%.dep,%<)
    # compilation 
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

Comment: Okkay, that actually did solve my problem, I also added $(CFLAGS) to the 1st recipe line for it to work.

Now, one last issue. it generates files .c.dep. for example: main.c.dep How can I make the files .dep only?

Comment: @MahmoudSaad Answer updated: you need to use `$(patsubst...)` command

Comment: I tried it but it gives out this error:
 # dep generation
gcc  -I ./include/CMSIS -I ./include/common -I ./include/msp432  -Wall -Werror -g -O0  -std=c99 -DHOST -MM main.c > %<
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 2